# How to plot text documents in a scatter map?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit to perform text classification and I'm trying to understand where the points lie with respect to my hyperplane to decide how to proceed. But I can't seem to plot the data that comes from the `CountVectorizer()` function. I used the following function: `pl.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1])` and it gives me the error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Any idea how to fix this?`

Comment: Is `X` a sparse matrix?

Comment: Yes, it is a sparse matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If `X` is a sparse matrix, you probably need `X = X.todense()` in order to get access to the data in the correct format. You probably want to check `X.shape` before doing this though, as if `X` is very large (but very sparse) it may consume a lot of memory when "densified".